# An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR-CAVT-01]

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ad-manager, google-ads-script, google-ads-data-hub

When I try to add my billing method in Google adward when I confirmed my credit card there was a error popUp which says:

> An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR-CAVT-01]

How can I complete the billing process?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).